# How to open a program on linux?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, tor

I've recently downloaded tor by using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

I run Linux Mint 17.3 "Rosa" and I have no idea where this file destination is. Could someone please tell me where it could possibly be or how I could open it with the terminal?

Comment: It seems to me that you might want to spend some time learning about the intricacies of the Linux File System, et al.  instead of jumping right into a specific item.  Take a look at the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com), [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com) and [The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org).  Furthermore, this site is a great wealth of knowledge, expertise and tips; therefore, feel free to ***search*** for relevant Questions and Answers to get a better understanding.

Comment: If you've installed `tor` successfully, then simply run `tor` in terminal use `man tor` for help

Comment: To see the files installed by package `tor`, use `dpkg -L tor`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you install a package that contains programs that you can usefully run without arguments, the package will add menu entries in the GUI. This isn't a mathematical certainty, but packages in Debian and Mint are supposed to do this.

If you want to list all the executable programs that a package contains, you can use the [`dpkg`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg) command, specifically its `-L` (`--listfiles`) option. `dpkg` is the command that manipulates installed packages; `apt` commands are about packages that are available in the distribution. To see just executables intended to be used by ordinary users, list files under `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. (See the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) for an explanation of the directories where Linux stores files.)

```
dpkg -L tor | egrep '^(/usr)?/bin/'
```

To also see commands that are generally only useful for system administrators (and thus are only in root's PATH), include `sbin` directories as well:

```
dpkg -L tor | egrep '^(/usr)?/sbin/'
```

In the case of tor, there's a system service, so you probably don't need to run any command. After installation, the next step is to [configure your browser or other software to use Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en#using).

Answer (score 0):

According to [where are apt-get files stored?](https://askubuntu.com/a/116576), the file is in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

For further reading:

- [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)
- [apt-get(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

In the original question, OP omitted the verb `install` from the command, which someone added in an edit.  However, OP said *downloaded*, which would be done using

```
sudo apt-get download tor
```

For clarification:

- [Difference between apt-get -d install & apt-get download](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463380/difference-between-apt-get-d-install-apt-get-download)
- [How do I use apt-get to only download packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47865/how-do-i-use-apt-get-to-only-download-packages)